# XSLT: Use multiple keys to make a grid

Tags: xml, xslt, key, xmltable

This is a follow on from my previous question. I started with a Table Grid which takes the format:

```
A1,B1,C1

A2,B2,C2

A3,B3,C3
```

Now this table of results repeats up to 5 times based on the instance value in the record. The values in the cells will be different for each instance of the table.

The XML that I am working with provides one cell value per record along with DayOfWeek (column), Stream(Row) and Instance (iteration of table) value.

Thanks to a previous helper I now have XSLT which lets me create a grid (columns x rows). However when I add an additional key (row-by-instance) to iterate through the instance, the XSLT fails.

The target result would look like:

```
Instance 1
 A1,B1,C1

 A2,  ,C2

 A3,B3,C3

Instance 2
 D1,E1,F1

 D2,  ,F2

 D3,E3,F3
```

There can be up to 5 instances, up to 7 days of the week and any number of rows.

**UPDATE**
I have updated the XSLT following a contribution from Michael, however I am still not there. The current result is

```
A1 A1 A1 A1 B1 B1 B1 C1 C1 C1 C1
A2 A2 A2 A2          C2 C2 C2 C2
A3 A3 A3 A3 B3 B3 B3 C3 C3 C3 C3

A1 A1 A1 A1 B1 B1 B1 C1 C1 C1 C1
A2 A2 A2 A2          C2 C2 C2 C2
A3 A3 A3 A3 B3 B3 B3 C3 C3 C3 C3
```

I have two iterations of the table, but they contain the same data, and columns are repeating too many times!

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:key name="row-by-instance" match="DataRow" use="Instance" />

<xsl:key name="row-by-stream" match="DataRow" use="concat(Instance, '|', Stream)" />
<xsl:key name="row-by-day" match="DataRow" use="concat(Instance, '|', Stream,'|',DayOfWeek)" />

<xsl:template match="/QueryResults">
    <!-- a column for each distinct day of week  -->
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="DataRow[generate-id() = generate-id(key('row-by-day',concat(Instance, '|', DayOfWeek))[1])]" />

    <xsl:for-each select="DataRow[count(. | key('row-by-instance', Instance)[1]) = 1]">
    <table border="1">
        <!--  a row for each distinct stream -->
        <!--<xsl:for-each select="DataRow[count(. | key('row-by-stream', Instance)[1]) = 1]">-->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('row-by-instance', Instance)[count(. | key('row-by-stream', concat(Instance, '|', Stream))[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="stream" select="key('row-by-stream', concat(Instance, '|', Stream))" />
            <tr>
                <!-- a cell for each column -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('row-by-instance', Instance)[count(. | key('row-by-day', concat(Instance, '|', Stream,'|',DayOfWeek))[1]) = 1]">
                    <xsl:sort select="DayOfWeek" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$stream[DayOfWeek = current()/DayOfWeek]/DisplayStuff" />
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QueryResults>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>1</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>A1</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>1</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>2</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>B1</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>1</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>3</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>C1</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>2</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>A2</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>

<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>2</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>3</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>C2</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>3</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>A3</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>3</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>2</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>B3</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <Instance>1</Instance>
    <Stream>3</Stream>
    <DayOfWeek>3</DayOfWeek>
    <DisplayStuff>C3</DisplayStuff>
</DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>1</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>D1</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>1</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>2</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>E1</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>1</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>3</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>F1</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>2</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>D2</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>

    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>2</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>3</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>E2</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>3</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>1</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>D3</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>3</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>2</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>E3</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>
    <DataRow>
        <Instance>2</Instance>
        <Stream>3</Stream>
        <DayOfWeek>3</DayOfWeek>
        <DisplayStuff>F3</DisplayStuff>
    </DataRow>       
</QueryResults>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by instance. What would be the expected  result of transforming the given input example?

Comment: Apologies - I have added an intended output and some more detail.

Comment: I don't understand your output. Is that supposed to be a separate table for each instance, or what?

Comment: Yes. Hence the for each loop is around the table.

Comment: You need to start by grouping the rows by instance. Then, **within each instance**, group them by stream. For this, you will need a key that concatenates instance and stream. You can find many examples of this method here, here is one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609476/complex-grouping-using-xslt-1-0/30650065#30650065

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have taken several wrong turns on the way. See if this helps you to get back on track:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="row-by-instance" match="DataRow" use="Instance" />
<xsl:key name="row-by-day" match="DataRow" use="DayOfWeek" />
<xsl:key name="row-by-stream" match="DataRow" use="concat(Instance, '|', Stream)" />

<xsl:template match="/QueryResults">
    <!-- a column for each distinct day of week (in any instance) -->
    <xsl:variable name="columns" select="DataRow[generate-id() = generate-id(key('row-by-day', DayOfWeek)[1])]" />
    <!-- a table for each distinct instance -->
    <xsl:for-each select="DataRow[count(. | key('row-by-instance', Instance)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:variable name="instance-rows" select="key('row-by-instance', Instance)" />
        <table border="1">
            <!-- a row for each distinct stream in this instance -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$instance-rows[generate-id() = generate-id(key('row-by-stream', concat(Instance, '|', Stream))[1])]">
                <xsl:variable name="stream-rows" select="key('row-by-stream', concat(Instance, '|', Stream))" />
                <tr>
                    <!-- a cell for each column -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$columns">
                        <xsl:sort select="DayOfWeek" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$stream-rows[DayOfWeek = current()/DayOfWeek]/DisplayStuff" />
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this generates a single set of columns for all tables, so that the tables will align. If you want each table to have its own columns (i.e. skip the days of week for which it has no data), then you will have to do things differently - most significantly, you will need to include `Instance` in the `row-by-day` key.