# XSLT grouping and transformation

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have to transform XML file by grouping identical nodes and putting them into identical parent node.
The example file looks like this:

```
<cars>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mondeo</model>
    <type>Hatchback</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mondeo</model>
    <type>Sedan</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Ford</make>
    <model>Mondeo</model>
    <type>Station wagon</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Citroen</make>
    <model>C5</model>
    <type>Sedan</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Citroen</make>
    <model>C4</model>
    <type>Hatchback</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Citroen</make>
    <model>C3</model>
    <type>Hatchback</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Opel</make>
    <model>Corsa</model>
    <type>Hatchback</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Opel</make>
    <model>Vectra</model>
    <type>Sedan</type>
  </car>
  <car>
    <seller>A</seller>
    <make>Opel</make>
    <model>Vectra</model>
    <type>Station wagon</type>
  </car>
</cars>
```

This file can include much more makes, models and types in a different order but there is always only one seller. I have to get it looking like that:

```
<cars>
  <seller>A</seller>
  <make name="Ford">
    <model name="Mondeo" type="Hatchback"/>
    <model name="Mondeo" type="Sedan"/>
    <model name="Mondeo" type="Station wagon"/>
  </make>
  <make name="Citroen">
    <model name="C5" type="Sedan"/>
    <model name="C4" type="Hatchback"/>
    <model name="C3" type="Hatchback"/>
  </make>
  <make name="Opel">
    <model name="Corsa" type="Hatchback"/>
    <model name="Vectra" type="Sedan"/>
    <model name="Vectra" type="Station wagon"/>
  </make>
</cars>
```

Before I tried that by checking if present model is the same as preceding-sibling but I couldn't to this to be "elastic" and could serve much more types of each model of each make.
I know how to transform one car node into desired format :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="CarsXSL" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="cars">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cars">
        <xsl:element name="seller">
          <xsl:value-of select="/cars/car[1]/seller/text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="make">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="/cars/car/make/text()"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:element name="model">
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
              <xsl:value-of select="/cars/car/make/model/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="type">
              <xsl:value-of select="/cars/car/make/model/type/text()"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
</localEntry>
```

but I don't know how to group it by make and model and then how to put them into indentical parent node.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is best done using the [Muenchian method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). There are numerous examples you can find on these pages.

Comment: Here's an example very similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30650065/3016153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: (*updated as suggested by @michael-hor257k*)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
   <xsl:key name="card" match="car" use="make"/>
   <xsl:key name="modeld" match="car" use="model"/>
   <xsl:key name="types" match="car" use="concat(make, '_', model)"/>
    
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="cars">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="car[generate-id() = generate-id(key('card', make)[1])]">
           <xsl:copy>
               <make name="{make}">
                   <xsl:for-each select="key('card', make)[generate-id() =
                       generate-id(key('modeld', model)[1])]">
                       <model name="{model}">
                           <xsl:copy-of select="key('types', concat(make, '_', model))/type"/>
                       </model>
                   </xsl:for-each>
               </make>
           </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8AD/1

For your Updated Question

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
   <xsl:key name="card" match="car" use="make"/>
    <xsl:key name="types" match="car" use="concat(make, '_', model, '_', type)"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="cars">
        <xsl:copy>
            <seller>
                <xsl:value-of select="//seller[1]"/>
            </seller>
            <car>
                <xsl:for-each select="//car[generate-id() = generate-id(key('card', make)[1])]">
                    <make name="{make}">
                        <xsl:for-each select="key('card', make)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('types', concat(make, '_', model, '_', type))[1])]">
                            <model name="{model}" type="{type}"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </make>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </car>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8AD/2

Comment: You are wasting half of the advantage of Muenchian grouping by using `//car[make = current()//make]` instead of `key('car', make)`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, updated answer as you suggest, thanks for highlighting this :)

Comment: @Rupesh_Kr Thank you! It works but ufortunately it returns each model in new car node (not like all Ford cars are in one node <car>, but every model is in another car node). The other thing is that the initial assumptions have been changed and I have to return all types as attributes of model, for example <model name="Corsa" type="Hatchback">

Comment: @JaggerNaught can you edit your question or create new question with new expected output

Comment: @Rupesh_Kr Thank you for trying to help me. As I wrote in previous comment -  the initial assumptions have been changed. I edited my question, so I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: All works just great! Thank you very much. I upvoted your answer but because of my low reputation (I'm new here) it isn't  publicly displayed.

Comment: @JaggerNaught you have to accept the answer if your requirement is done  (No reputation is required for that), so this thread is close,